# Flink Disk I/O Behavior

Tags: apache-flink

I am curious about Flink's disk I/O behavior. I know there is a pair of reader and writer threads for each temp directory as mentioned by the advanced section in the Flink's configuration page. I assume these threads are used to read intermediate results stored locally by Flink.

But how does Flink handle the very first data coming from say HDFS? More specifically, will data source thread cooperate with another reader thread to read the data from HDFS? Or even the reader thread is exactly the same thread with the temp's reader thread? Or the data source thread will do the reading by itself?